# It is possible avoid only external connections to my xdebug with Ngnix and PHPStorm?

Tags: php, debugging, nginx, phpstorm, xdebug

I have a development environment in my computer, I use nginx and PHPStorm with Xdebug for my debugging, I need to debug in my environment but other people also connects to my machine for testing purpose, it is possible that when I active my debug this only affect me and not for they?

Update:

My xdebug.ini looks like this:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626/xdebug.so
xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_log = /tmp/xdebug.log
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_port = 9001
xdebug.remote_autostart = On
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = /tmp
xdebug.remote_host = localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

The key here is the setting: xdebug.remote_host. The default value is *localhost*, which guarantees that Xdebug only *contact a debug client which is listening on your **localhost** and configured port*

More detail: [Xdebug Settings Document](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_host)
& [Remote Debugging Document](http://xdebug.org/docs/remote)

Comment: If debugging is disable -- how is he supposed to trigger browser based debug?

Comment: @LazyOne: I suggested him to disable ***remote*** debugging, not debugging itself

Comment: Well -- the docs say *"This switch controls whether Xdebug should try to contact a debug client"*. With `remote_enable=0` xdebug will not be attempting to connect to client to debug the page ...

Comment: Thanks much @LazyOne, I updated my answer to emphasize/correct the setting which needs to be set.

Comment: That doesn't work for me, I have this in my xdebug.ini: zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626/xdebug.so xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM xdebug.remote_log = /tmp/xdebug.log xdebug.remote_enable = 1 xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0 xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp xdebug.remote_port = 9001 xdebug.remote_autostart = On xdebug.profiler_enable = 1 xdebug.profiler_output_dir = /tmp xdebug.remote_host = localhost And I have requests in my PHPStorm when the people use my machine for testing.

Comment: Please try: 
xdebug.remote_host         = "192.168.1.2" (or your IPaddress)
xdebug.remote_port         = 9005
*Note:* Use your preferred port. Config PHPStorm to listen on that port.